# How to flatten list of lists?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a query, which has one to many relation with LegalEntity table, my goal is to get a List of all LegalEntityIds. At this point I have following select which produces `List<IEnumerable<string>>`, is there a quick and efficient way without looping and creating separate list to flatten the inner lists into one.

```
var legalEntityIds = query.Select(x => x.LegalEntities.Select(y => y.LegalEntityId)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-6.0):

```
var legalEntityIds = 
    query.SelectMany(x => x.LegalEntities).Select(y => y.LegalEntityId).ToList();
```

or, using query syntax:

```
var legalEntityIds = (
    from item in query
    from legalEntity in item
    select legalEntity.LegalEntityId
).ToList();
```